# Choice of Sparse Matrix in Numpy and Scipy

Tags: numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix in the following way: The matrix has `n k` columns. For each row of the matrix, there can be k nonzero elements, and these elements will always lie on the position `row[mk:(m+1)k]` where `m`is an integer with different value for each row. The following is an example of such matrix, with `n=2` and `k=3`

```
matrix = [
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
]
```

My goal is to multiple this matrix with a dense vector. I guess I can store this matrix using some sparse matrix format of scipy, but I don't know which one is a good choice for my purpose. Any suggestions?

Comment: For calculation purposes the `csr` format is most useful.  But the `sparse` code usually can convert the other formats automatically to this.  So the more important question is, which format is easiest to define.  For iterative definitions `lil` and `dok` are best, but the `coo` style of input is usually most efficient.

Comment: But the result of multiplying a sparse matrix by a dense vector is (usually) a dense matrix or array.  In that case it might not be worth your while to use sparse at all - unless the matrix is really large, and very sparse.